# What is this brown spot on my bearded dragon?

Tags: health, skin-condition, bearded-dragon

I inherited an almost 2 year old male Bearded Dragon, He's awesome but I've only had him a few days and I've noticed a weird brown/black color on him. It looks a little crusty.

Does it look normal because I'm not sure? He eats and drinks water, seems healthy.  [image]

Comment: I cannot answer the question, but I advise you to consult a vet anyways. Reptiles hide discomfort and pain as long as possible to not appear weak and become prey. That your dragon eats and drinks means that it's probably not a medical emergency, but it doesn't mean that everything is fine.

Comment: Everything looks normal to me from this photo.